# TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT does not work as expected

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe-animate

Hello there i had another problem but this one is weird and does not work as expected

I had a text input component i add a function to it, when a user type a text it start to search in an array, the problem is when i type the first letter the output is blank and when i type the second letter the function reads only the first letter
here is the code
workArray is the object that stores workTitle and workCost

```
work.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, inputInWorkBox);
function inputInWorkBox(TextEvent) {
    trace("Function worked: "+work.text.toLowerCase());
    todayWorkList.removeAll();
        var typedWork = work.text.toLowerCase();
        var fullWork:String = "";
    for (i = 0; i <= workNumber; i++) {
        fullWork = (workArray[i].workTitle).toLowerCase();
        if (fullWork.search(typedWork) != -1) {
            todayWorkList.visible = true;
            todayWorkList.addItem({
                label: (workArray[i].workTitle),
                data: workArray[i]
            });
        }
    }
}
```

here is the output

Function worked:          // i typed a
Function worked: a        // i typed ab
Function worked: ab       // i typed abc
Function worked: abc     // i typed abcd

BTW: i don't want to use CHANGE Event because the data in the text input changed by other functions to display some data i want it to call the function only when a user type inside that specific text input

thanx in advance

Answer (score 4):

Here's the quote from the [CHANGE event](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:change):

> Dispatched after a control value is modified, unlike the **textInput**
> event, which is dispatched before the value is modified.

That means that **TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT** is dispatched **before** the text in the **TextField** is actually changed, which totally agrees with the results you get (although it is not explicitly mentioned in the [TEXT_INPUT chapter](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:textInput) itself) **AND** works **EXACTLY** as expected.

Then, the documentation states that [TEXT_INPUT event](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#event:textInput) has a **text** property which contains the new content of the **TextField**.

Thus, your code should be something like

```
work.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);

// This is a wrong thing to do: inputInWorkBox(TextEvent)
// Do not declare entities with the names similar to class names.
// Use some simple variable names instead.
function onInput(e:TextEvent):void
{
    // Extract the new text (which is not passed to the TextField yet).
    var aText:String = e.text.toLowerCase();
    
    trace("The new text is:", aText);
    
    // Proceed processing aText variable from here on.
```

Comment: I already tried that in line 5 of my code 
```var typedWork = work.text.toLowerCase();``` and get the same result, and I was helpless so i used CHANGE event and it work as I want without calling the function if the text was changed from other functions only when I typed inside the box 
 thanks

Comment: @AliNabeel No, **work.text** is NOT THE SAME as **e.text**. Pleas re-read my explanations until you spot the difference between accessing the **TextField** that does not have the final **text** and reading the event property that DOES have the final text.

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice that, it was agreat help